# "No Such File Error" when trying to open each fasta file stored in an array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, foreach, directory

How can I open each file in a folder in sequential order, perform a regex search on the contents of each file, and store the matches in another array? 
Here is what I have so far:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings; 
    use strict; 
    use diagnostics; 

    my $dir = ("/path/to/folder"); 
    my @ArrayofFiles;   
    my @TrimmedSequences; 

    opendir( my $dh, $dir ) || die;

    #make an array of fasta files from a folder
    while ( readdir $dh ) {                
        chomp;
        my $fileName = $_;
        if ($fileName =~ /\.fasta.*/) {
            push(@ArrayofFiles, $fileName); 
        }
    } 
    #this diagnostic print statement shows that I do get the proper files into the target array. I leave it commented out when I run the script. 
    #print join("\n", @ArrayofFiles), "\n";

    #now I want to open each file in the array, search file contents, and add the result to another array
    foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles){ 
        open (my $sequence, '<', $file) or die $!;
        while (my $line = <$sequence>) {
            if ($line =~ m/(CTCCCA)[TAGC]+(TCAGGA)/) { 
            push(@TrimmedSequences, $line); 
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:
"Uncaught exception from user code: No such file or directory at /Users/roblogan/Documents/BIOL6309/Manipulating fast5 files/Attempt 5 line 23."
Line 24 is "open (my $sequence, '<', $file) or die $!;"

My diagnostic print statement shows that I am working with an array of the expected fasta files.

I would be very grateful for any help I can get. Thank you so much. 
-Rob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I open files returned by Perl's readdir?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557942/why-cant-i-open-files-returned-by-perls-readdir)

Comment: @MattJacob It would be nice if the duplicate question had an answer that shows how to fix the problem, like mine does.

Comment: Thanks for the link Matt. After looking it over, I changed to a glob function, which returned the entire directory description of the files rather than just the file name itself. This was likely one of the problems I was having. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Barmar There are other posts with better answers than the one I flagged, but none with better questions (i.e., the question obscures the real problem).

Comment: @MattJacob I hate when that happens. Maybe use this one as your duplicate in the future, the question is a common pattern and the answer is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ArrayOfFiles` just contains the filenames, it doesn't include the directory prefix. So you're trying to access the filenames in the current directory rather than the directory you listed.

Use:

```
push(@ArrayofFiles, "$dir/$fileName");
```

to get the full path.

Comment: Wow, that was a fast response!

Comment: When I added the modification you suggested, I got another error- indicating that the files are numeric in division (/). That made perl think I was giving it a numeric value. I just now changed my code to use the glob function, which returned the full file name with directory, according to the diagnostic print statement. The foreach loop still seems to be problematic- even though it seems to be working on "/Users/roblogan/Documents/FakeFastaFilesAgain/sequence.fasta" rather than simply "sequence.fasta" etc. Any insights?

Comment: Did you forget to put the quotes around the variables? That should make it do string substitution, not division.

Comment: That solves the problem! Thank you very much for your lightening fast help Barmar. Deeply appreciate it. The diagnostic print now returns the full directory path for all the files.